# Comparing decimals of given numbers VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to see if two given numbers, for example 1.134 and 1.135 have the same decimals. So far everything works correctly, but when working with number with a large number of decimals I have a problem:
I get the following error for the following input 0.841666666666667, 0.841468253968254:

```
    Unhandled Exception:
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
```

This is my code

```
Function TrueOrFalse(ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double, ByVal n as Integer) As Boolean
   
    For i As Integer = 1 To n+1
        
        If  CInt(x) <> CInt(y) Then
            Return False
        End If
        x *= 10
        y *= 10
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

I understand that it's because the Int type cannot contains that much digits, and when changing CInt to CLng everything works perfectly. Problem: I cannot use CLng. Is there any alternatives ?
Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use CLng?

Comment: That's the instructions, I know that it's weird

Comment: You could "cut off" the part on the left side of the `.` after you compared it for equality, since you already know that this part is equal (i.e. `x = x mod 1`, and the same for `y`).

Comment: EDIT: It worked, thank you very much for your help, if you want you can submit your answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Done. Glad to hear that it helped. Have fun coding!

Comment: I have also added a simpler solution to solve your underlying problem as a separate answer, just in case you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could "cut off" the integer part after you compared it for equality, since you already know that this part is equal, i.e., instead of

```
CInt(1.134) = CInt(1.135)
CInt(11.34) = CInt(11.35)
CInt(113.4) = CInt(113.5)
etc.
```

you just compare

```
CInt(1.134) = CInt(1.135)
CInt(1.34) = CInt(1.35)
CInt(3.4) = CInt(3.5)
```

That way, your values won't get too large.

---

How to do that? Before multiplying `x` and `y` by ten, you remove the integer part, either straightforward with

```
x = x - CInt(x)
y = y - CInt(y)
```

or by abusing the [`Mod` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/mod-operator):

```
x = x Mod 1
y = y Mod 1
```

---

A few side notes:

- `TrueOrFalse` is *not* a great name for your method, since it does not describe what the method does. `AreEqualUpToNDecimalPlaces` would be a better name.
- Beware of [floating point imprecisions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/87698) when using the `Double` data type.
- In case this is not a toy problem for educational purposes, note that there are simpler solutions to your concrete problem (I have added one example as a [separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65570584/87698)).

Answer (score 0):

If you exceed the range of an Integer, don't use an Integer. You can truncate Doubles just fine using [`Math.Truncate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.truncate?view=net-5.0#System_Math_Truncate_System_Double_).

Using that built-in functionality, your method could be reduced to the following one-liner:

```
Function AreEqualUpToNDecimalPlaces(ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double, ByVal n as Integer) As Boolean
    Return Math.Truncate(x * (10.0^n)) = Math.Truncate(y * (10.0^n))
End Function
```

Test cases:

```
Console.WriteLine(AreEqualUpToNDecimalPlaces(1.134, 1.135, 2))  ' True
Console.WriteLine(AreEqualUpToNDecimalPlaces(1.134, 1.135, 3))  ' False

Console.WriteLine(AreEqualUpToNDecimalPlaces(0.841666666666667, 0.841468253968254, 3))  ' True
Console.WriteLine(AreEqualUpToNDecimalPlaces(0.841666666666667, 0.841468253968254, 4))  ' False
```